# Cannot install IIS Administration Pack for IIS7

Tags: windows-7, installation, iis, iis-7, iis-7.5

I have IIS7 running on Windows 7 Enterprise.

When I try to install [IIS 7 Administration Pack](http://www.iis.net/expand/AdministrationPack) I get the following error:

[image]

How can I troubleshoot this to find out what is causing the installer from failing to initialize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 7 Comes with IIS 7.5, not IIS 7.0 and the Administration Pack is not compatible with it.

It looks like the tools are now integrated, as Windows 7 is tied with Windows Server 2008 R2, I am guessing the same is true.

### From IIS.Net

Integration of Administration Pack Extension into the Windows Server OS
We integrated the functionality of the IIS7 Administration Pack into the Windows Server 2008 R2 installation, which provides customers with:

> 1.
>         Integrated administration support in IIS Manager for the ASP.NET authorization, custom errors, FastCGI, and Request Filtering features.
>
> 2.
>         Configuration Manager, which gives you a visual editor for managing the IIS7 configuration system. If you want to check it out, Carlos Aguilar Mares, our IIS Dev Manager, wrote a comprehensive blog on the Config Editor's capabilities. My favorite part of Configuration Editor is the script generation functionality -- comes in very handy with demos! :-)

Comment: Oh, i wasn't aware that Windows 7 comes with IIS 7.5
It appears that IIS 7.5 has Admin Pack already installed.